Nextjs and qr-code-styling error, self is not defined

"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import QRCodeStyling from "qr-code-styling";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ShareBtn = ({ recipe }: any) => {
    const [qrPopupOpen, setQrPopupOpen]: any = useState(false);
    const [qrCodeInstance, setQRCodeInstance] = useState<QRCodeStyling | null>(
        null
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (qrPopupOpen) {
            const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                backgroundOptions: {
                    color: "transparent",
                },
                dotsOptions: {
                    type: "classy-rounded",
                },
                data: `/recipes/${recipe.id}`,
                imageOptions: {
                    crossOrigin: "anonymous",
                    margin: 20,
                },
            });

            setQRCodeInstance(qrCode);
        }
    }, [qrPopupOpen]);

    const toggleQrPopup = () => {
        setQrPopupOpen(!qrPopupOpen);
    };

    const openSharePopup = () => {
        toggleQrPopup();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="outline" className="w-full" onClick={openSharePopup}>
                Share
            </Button>
            {qrPopupOpen && qrCodeInstance && (
                <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-neutral-950/25 backdrop-blur-sm z-[999]">
                    <div className="bg-neutral-200 p-8 rounded-xl relative max-w-[90vw] max-h-[90vh] overflow-auto">
                        <button
                            className="absolute top-4 right-4 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800"
                            onClick={toggleQrPopup}
                        >
                            <p>close</p>
                        </button>

                        <div
                            className="bg-transparent"
                            ref={(node) => node && qrCodeInstance?.append(node)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShareBtn;


So, I get the issue, status 500, "self is not defined" my code itself works on the UI but the error is in the console.
I don't need error in the console, I just am trying to render a QR code on a popup, and im 100% sure there are no issues with the popup.

GET /recipes 500 in 397ms
 ⨯ ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yevheniiasimaka/Desktop/recipe-website/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)

Here is again the error that I'm getting, I am making a recipe website but and I want to add the ability to share by QR code, but however, it doesnt work because it says self is not defined, according to some github posts its because window isn't rendered at the begining, so I have to wrap my code in useEffect, but I already did that in the first place, so it wasn't helpful


This is a known issue, as referenced in issue #89 and issue 172. The qr-code-styling library currently only works on the client side because it relies on the window object, which is not available on the server side.
Solution 1: Use Dynamic Import with next/dynamic to import ShareBtn component
const ShareBtn = dynamic(() => import('@/path/to/ShareBtn'), {
  ssr: false,
});

Solution 2: ES6 Dynamic Import
Alternatively, you can use the ES6 import() function to dynamically load the library in ShareBtn component when it's needed:

const ShareBtn = ({ recipe }: any) => {
    // other code
    const [qrCode,setQrCode] = useState();
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current && qrCode) {
            qrCode.append(ref.current);
        }
    }, [ref, qrCode]);


    useEffect(() => {
        // Dynamically import qr-code-styling only client-side
        if (ref.current) {
            import("qr-code-styling").then(({default: QRCodeStyling}) => {
                const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
                   width: 300,
                   height: 300,
                   backgroundOptions: {
                       color: "transparent",
                   },
                   dotsOptions: {
                       type: "classy-rounded",
                   },
                   data: `/recipes/${recipe.id}`,
                   imageOptions: {
                       crossOrigin: "anonymous",
                       margin: 20,
                   },
                });

                setQrCode(qrCode);
            });
        }
    }, [ref]);

   return (
        <div ref={ref}/>
    );
}

Both solutions ensure that the qr-code-styling library is only loaded in the browser environment, avoiding errors related to self not defined on the server.
